# angular-tag-cloud link modification in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-template

Using this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tag-cloud-module

I am wanting to call a function on the link property instead of providing or passing in a link to an external website. For instance, the user can click a word and some function is called based on the word that they click. Does anyone have any knowledge or experience doing that with this package ?

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tag-cloud-module) you provided, has the answer of your question itself.

It can be done by detecting the event that is triggered when we click on any item from the word cloud.

Add a function like this, which u want to call on item click.

```
yourDesiredFunction(data: CloudData){
console.log('hey you clicked on',data.text);
```

}

and in html you can write as,

```
<angular-tag-cloud [data]="data" [width]="options.width **(clicked)="yourDesiredFunction($event)"**>
</angular-tag-cloud>
```

This will call your desired function on click.

If you face any issue on this, feel free to ask.